# How do I search specific content in my recent files on MacOSX 12.1 (21C52)?

Tags: mac, filesystem, search

Is there a way to search some string in file content, that I can narrow down the following filters:

1. Recently created (< 20 days).
2. Text file (but not surely with a `.txt` extension).
3. Might be in any folder on this machine.

Answer (score 1):

What is a text file? That is a bit ambiguous. In terms of Spotlight metadata  I define it as having the `public.text` as one item in its `kMDItemContentTypeTree` metadata item.

With that you can search in Finder with something like this:

[image: Search for recent text files]

Just enter your search string in the "Search for:" box.

The key (not obvious) item in this search is the Raw Query.

Firstly it is not an obvious search criterion. To see "Raw Query" as a search criterion (like "Name" or "Created Date") choose "Other" in the drop down box and scroll down to "Raw query" and tick the In Menu selection.
[image: Raw query]

Now the magic bit. The raw query you need is `kMDItemContentTypeTree == "public.text"cd`

I found this using the `mdls` Terminal command on a candidate for being a text file, like this:

```
mdls /Users/gilby/Applications/KM/apptagset.sh
_kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions      = "apptagset.sh"
kMDItemContentCreationDate             = 2022-01-22 06:05:07 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking     = 2022-01-22 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate         = 2022-01-22 06:05:07 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate_Ranking = 2022-01-22 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentType                     = "public.shell-script"
kMDItemContentTypeTree                 = (
    "public.shell-script",
    "public.script",
    "public.source-code",
    "public.plain-text",
    "public.text",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                       = 2022-01-22 06:05:07 +0000
kMDItemDateAdded_Ranking               = 2022-01-22 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                     = "apptagset.sh"
kMDItemDocumentIdentifier              = 0
......
```

You may find that my raw query does not meet your definition of a text file - e.g. should that include .rtf (rich text files) files or not. You might prefer the raw query `kMDItemContentTypeTree == "public.plain-text"cd` because .rtf are `public.text`, but not `public.plain-text`.

But play with it a bit.

Further exploration:

In Terminal you can use the `mdfind` command to perform Spotlight queries. Like this:

`mdfind '(kMDItemContentTypeTree == "public.text"cd && (kMDItemFSCreationDate >= "$time.today(-20d)" && kMDItemFSCreationDate < "$time.today(+1d)"))'`

If you find this just too excruciating, I recommend the (not free) GUI app [HoudahSpot](https://www.houdah.com/houdahSpot/) which makes this relatively easy:

[image: HoudahSpot example]

And it will tell me the raw query if I want to use it with `mdls`.

[image: HS raw query]

Comment: If "Might be any folder" really means just that, you will have to add criteria a) System Files are included and b) File visibility Visible or invisible.